# How to correctly download firebase storage images into recycelrView

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage, android-glide

I have recyclerview and in every row I have an image that I load with [firebase storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage). It seems like the image loading is affecting the scrolling performance of the recyclerView.

I am using glide to load the images that I got from firebase inside `onBindViewHolder` by calling `imageLoadGlide` method like this:

```
//Download image from firebase Storage and set gameImage("ImageView") image.
private void imageLoadGlide(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, final QuestionsHolder questionsHolder) {
    //for firebase storage
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    // Create a storage reference from our app
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
    storageRef.child(documentSnapshot
            .get("image").toString())
            .getDownloadUrl()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            //this part is loading image from url library
            Glide
                    .with(context.getApplicationContext())   // pass Context
                    .load(uri)// pass the image url
                    .centerCrop() // optional scaletype
                    .crossFade() //optional - to enable image crossfading
                    .transform(new CircleTransform(context))//transfoms the imageView onto circle with the custon class CircleTransform
                    .into(questionsHolder.gameImage); // the ImageView to which the image is to be loaded
            //stop the loading bar from spinning
            questionsHolder.loadProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}
```

The download works fine but it makes the scrolling super slow.

I have no idea why this is happening because I compress the images before uploading them so I don't think that this is a problem of image weight.

The image compress is made like this :

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) questionImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 10, baos);
byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
UploadTask uploadTask = mountainImagesRef.putBytes(data);
```

Any ideas on why this is happening and how can I avoid this?

**Here is `onBindViewHolder` for @Vadim Eksler request:**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final QuestionsHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.gameImage.setImageBitmap(null);
    setInfoForViews(holder, result.get(position));

    imageLoadGlide(result.get(position), holder);

    setOnClicksListners(holder, position);
    setRankTextView(position, holder);
    if (position == result.size() - 1 && !endOfDocs && next != null) {
        loadMoreDocs(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your `onBindViewHolder` method?

Comment: @VadimEksler just updated the question

Comment: every time that `onBindViewHolder` is called you go to firebase and run glide. I think you need to save image uris to your object and make check `if(result.get(position).getUri() == null) {imageLoadGlide(result.get(position), holder); } else { make just glide.load ... }`. also you need to remove this `setImageBitmap(null);` and turn on glide cache.

Comment: first for circle image use circleImage library and second try to get low size of image and third is use thumbnail in glide. It will perfectly work for you

Comment: I have added an answer based on all of the comments in here.
@Vadim Eksler that was good advice 
@ BlackBlind I have seen some problems with circleImage  library so I prefer not to use it, lowering the size of the images is a good tip and i am using really small images, and I will look at the tuimbnail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This answer is based on all the comments together.**

So as mentioned in the comments what I did wrong is that every time that `onBindViewHolder` was called I have pulled the image from firebase again and again - this causes poorly recyclerView performance.

### What I did to fix it:

I have used `flyweight` design pattern to load the image only for the first time from firebase and after that simply recycle this image for the next time `onBindViewHolder` will get called.

- First I created a map as a global variable:

  `private  Map<String, Bitmap> flyweight = new HashMap<>();`
- after that when the image is loaded from the first time I will save it for later when `onBindViewHolder` will get called again:

  Inside `onBindViewHolder` :

  ```
  if (flyweight.get(result.get(position).get("image").toString()) == null) {
      imageLoadGlide(result.get(position), holder); // load the image
  } else {
      //recycle the image that i already have
      holder.gameImage.setImageBitmap(flyweight.get(result.get(position).get("image").toString()));
  }
  ```

And the last thing is to add my image to the map that I created after the image is successfully pulled :

```
flyweight.put(documentSnapshot.get("image").toString(), resource);
```